# Android Calendar get current week, previous weeks, and next weeks

Tags: java, android

I am attempting to retrieve the current days in the week IE: Mon-Sun. I then have two buttons, Previous and Next that should retrieve the next and previous weeks dates. This should allow me to rotate through the weeks of the year indefinitely.

1. Previous Week: 2017/05/8-2017/05/14
2. Loaded Week: 2017/05/15-2017/05/21
3. Next week: 2017/05/22-2017/05/28

The code loads the middle dates Mon-Sun. When I hit the next button it takes me to the next set of days for the next week. When I hit Previous from here it skips the initial loaded week and jumps to the Next week dates. The same occurs when I go the other way with Previous to Next. When I continue hitting the next and previous buttons they do not continue loading new weeks.

What am I doing wrong?

Initial load code:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

days = new String[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    days[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

Next Week Code:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);

days = new String[7];

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    days[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

Previous Week Code:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd");
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);

days = new String[7];

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    days[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

Solution:

`Calendar calendar; // Stick this at the start of your code`

Initial load code:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd");
calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);

days = new String[7];
for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    days[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

Next Week Code:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd");
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);

days = new String[7];

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    days[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

Previous Week Code:

```
DateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd");
calendar.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.MONDAY);
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -7);

days = new String[7];

for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
{
    days[i] = format.format(calendar.getTime());
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
}
```

Comment: *"What am I doing wrong?"* You're not remembering where you are. Your "Next Week Code" will always get next week, **relative to today**, not relative to currently displayed week.

Comment: How would you suggest that I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that by calling the: Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); each time it was confusing the calendar.

The solution is to remove the Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(); from the previous and Next code and implement a variable Calander calendar; at the start of your code. I will edit the original code with the solution.

Comment: Don't "edit the original code with the solution." That's what answers are for. As it stands, this answer is little more than a comment.